# If $u \in L^1(0,\infty)$, then $|u(x)| \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $u \in L^1(0,\infty)$. Does this mean necessarily that $|u(x)| \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$?

I think it has to decay otherwise the integral will be infinite. Can I get a hint on how to prove this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is not true. A counterexample is the function that is equal to $1$ only for intervals of the type $[2^n, 2^n + 2^{-n}]$ for every integer $n$.

Because the intervals on which it is positive are getting thinner and thinner, the integral of the function is positive, even though it is equal to $1$ even for some very large values of $x$.

Comment: Thank you. Is it true if $u \in L^1(X)$ is also continuous? I think your example cannot be made continuous without increasing the integral to ifninity.

Comment: @Abbre No you can replace the steps in my counterexample with tiny (very thin) triangles.

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks

Comment: @Abbre If my answer is what you need, please consider upvoting and accepting it...

Comment: Hmm I cannot upvote but I accepted it.

Comment: @Abbre: I will upvote in your stead. It's a good answer. +1.